# How can I access/use javascript objects from a drop down list(selector list)

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use a HTML drop-down list (`<select>`) to reference a list of objects (like `Emp_2`). I then want to use the selected object and access its `TCL` property. I am concatenating the selected option value result (with **.TCL** ) to reference the selected objects property). Everything seems to work except that `getElementById('id')` returns a string value rather then the object. The string `emp` (after being concatenated) ends up with the right name (`Emp_2.TCL`) but does not reference my object property (`Emp_2.TCL`).

```
var Emp_1 ={fname: "Mark", lname: "Arm", wage: 12.00, OT_wage: 18.00, TCL: 25.53 };
var Emp_2 ={fname: "Ed", lname: "Del", wage: 15.00, OT_wage: 28.00, TCL: 25.00 };
var Emp_3 ={fname: "Filen", lname: "Haro", wage: 16.00, OT_wage: 24.00, TCL: 20.00 };
var Emp_4 ={fname: "Javi", lname: "Loz", wage: 15.00, OT_wage: 22.00, TCL: 26.99};

function tech_select(x=""){
    var num_of_emp = 5;
    var sel = '<select id="tech_selector_'+x+'"> \n ';
    sel += '<option value="select" selected="selected">Select Technician</option> \n ';
    i=1;
    while(i<num_of_emp){
        var emp = 'Emp_'+i;
        sel += '<option value="'+emp+'">' + eval('Emp_'+i+'.fname') + ' ' + eval('Emp_'+i+'.lname') + '</option> \n ';
        i++;
    }
    sel +=  '</select> \n ';
    return sel;
}

function emp_tcl_total(row_num=2){
    var r = row_num;
    var emp ;
    emp = document.getElementById('tech_selector_'+r).value;
    emp += '.TCL'; //This is building a string**"Emp_2.TCL"** rather then the desired object named **Emp_2.TCL**.
    document.getElementById('tcl_'+r).innerHTML = emp; // emp needs to be an object name not a string. Emp_2.TCL is an object
    alert(emp); //returns Emp_2.TCL
    alert(Emp_2.TCL); //returns 25
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an array instead of separate variables:

```
var Emp = [];
Emp['someindex'] ={fname: "Mark", lname: "Arm", wage: 12.00, OT_wage: 18.00, TCL: 25.53 };
```

...then look up the data based on the selection index value.